# Where can I find history files structure (transactions and ledger files specifically)?

Tags: xdr, history

I'm trying to extract history files from the archive, I understood that transaction file is built of pairs: (32bit length,data), but when I try to extract the data from a single stream I get error:
tx_json = JSON.stringify(StellarSdk.xdr.TransactionEnvelope.fromXDR(data_b64, 'base64'));
Error: XDR Read Error: Unknown PublicKeyType member for value 8851437

Comparing the base64 I get from the data and the base64 of a single transaction envelope I can see that my data_b64 includes additional data prior to the TransactionEnvelope, but what is the structure of this header?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly moving this to higher visibility, but the structure is `TrancationHistoryEntry`, which you can find in the [XDR on Github](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/xdr/Stellar-ledger.x).